# 12.04 Migration Process time delay

Tags: cpu-usage, linux-kernel, high-load

We have an issue in our server that is the migration process in taking time and also the load in the server is getting high due to that.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
Linux kvm-cloud 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root         6     2 17 Nov25 ?        01:51:10 [migration/0]
root         8     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:44:56 [migration/1]
root        13     2 12 Nov25 ?        01:24:30 [migration/2]
root        17     2 17 Nov25 ?        01:51:03 [migration/3]
root        21     2 13 Nov25 ?        01:26:44 [migration/4]
root        25     2 17 Nov25 ?        01:51:03 [migration/5]
root        29     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:50:09 [migration/6]
root        33     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:49:58 [migration/7]
root        37     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:50:09 [migration/8]
root        41     2 13 Nov25 ?        01:29:26 [migration/9]
root        45     2 13 Nov25 ?        01:25:29 [migration/10]
root        49     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:47:29 [migration/11]
root        53     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:46:22 [migration/12]
root        57     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:45:02 [migration/13]
root        61     2 17 Nov25 ?        01:51:37 [migration/14]
root        65     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:47:59 [migration/15]
root        69     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:47:59 [migration/16]
root        73     2 17 Nov25 ?        01:51:37 [migration/17]
root        77     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:47:53 [migration/18]
root        81     2 17 Nov25 ?        01:54:00 [migration/19]
root        85     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:46:04 [migration/20]
root        89     2 16 Nov25 ?        01:46:04 [migration/21]
root        93     2 12 Nov25 ?        01:21:52 [migration/22]
root        97     2 13 Nov25 ?        01:29:45 [migration/23]

ps -auxf | sort -nr -k 3 | head -10
root        81 17.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov25 114:00  \_ [migration/19]
root        73 16.9  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov25 111:37  \_ [migration/17]
root        61 16.9  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov25 111:37  \_ [migration/14]
root         6 16.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov25 111:10  \_ [migration/0]
root        25 16.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov25 111:03  \_ [migration/5]
root        17 16.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Nov25 111:03  \_ [migration/3
```

Have any one come across with this issue ? please let me know if there is any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

"migration" is the kernel proces that distributes processes over cores, you should see one process for each core.

Typically those threads consuming a lot of resources is only a symptom of another issue, not the cause of a high load.

But: one method to prevent processes from migrating is to pin them to a specific single core or a range of cores. From the manpage of `taskset`:

> taskset  is  used to set or retrieve the CPU affinity of a running
>   process given its PID or to launch a new COMMAND with a given  CPU 
>   affinity.    CPU affinity is a scheduler property that "bonds" a
>   process to a given set of CPUs on the system.  The Linux scheduler 
>   will  honor  the given  CPU  affinity  and  the  process will not run
>   on any other CPUs.
>
> Note that the Linux scheduler also supports natural CPU  affinity: 
>   the scheduler attempts to keep processes on the same CPU as long as
>   practical for performance reasons.  Therefore, forcing a specific CPU 
>   affinity is useful only in certain applications.

Comment: But the issue with me is that this is a server which run KVM instance, we do have other machines which runs KVM and it doesn;t have this issue acuatlly the server is working for but the migration process in this server is showing 17 Hours and other server are at 0
at this time the wa is also getting higher need to dig further

Comment: You still can do cpu pinning for KVM virtual guests. `virsh capabilities` will list a.o. the physical cpu's and cores and with `virsh vcpupin domain` you can set cpu affinity for the virtual guest.